# Opening powershell from python

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I would like to open a powershell from my python script, then launch another python script in this newly created powershell.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("start C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0", shell=True) 
# Here, I would like to write this in the new opened powershell : python ./hello_world.py (then press ENTER)

input("end")
```

Any idea how I can do that ? Thanks and have a good day !

I tried the subprocess.Popen + communicate but nothing was written in my new powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use `os.system()`

```
import os

os.system("start powershell python path_to_file") 
# some code
```

Comment: Not really what I need for 3 reasons :
1/ I would like to open in a new window to be able to see logs for each python file I run
2/ I would like to use powershell (blue background)
3/ I would like the new powershell to be independant from parent (meaning I can close parent and still have the child powershells)

Comment: if you use `threading` or `multiprocessing` you can achieve this

Comment: try `os.startfile("powershell.exe")`

Comment: This works perfectly to open the new powershell, but then how do I write "python ./hello_world.py" in my new powershell please?

Comment: ok I found a way `os.system("start powershell python path_to_file")`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", "python hello-world.py"], capture_output=True, cwd="C:\\your\\path")
```

Will output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['powershell', '-Command', 'python hello-world.py'], returncode=0, stdout=b'hello world\r\n', stderr=b'')
```

Where `stdout=b'hello world\r\n'` is your output.

Answer (score 0):

I think subprocess is not intended to interact with active window. but to send stream data to pipeline.

try using [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to interact with Powershell window.